# Creating a gruntfile to compile Jekyll and push a subfolder to Github

Tags: coffeescript, gruntjs, npm, jekyll

I have a gruntfile that compiles my jekyll for me, and I want it to push the compiled folder up to my github and ignore the main folder that Gruntfile resides in. I'm doing this utilizing [grunt git-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git-deploy). I'm getting "Arguments to path.join must be strings. Use --force to continue". But everything is in a string as it's suppose to be and is documented, unless I'm missing something which is quite possible because I haven't slept in a day or so.

Here is the portion in question

```
git_deploy:
  your_target:
    options:
      url: 'git@github.com:Diope/diope.github.io.git'
      message: 'new post'
    src: "/_site"
```

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The example from [grunt git-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git-deploy) is:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  git_deploy: {
    your_target: {
      options: {
        url: 'git@github.com:example/repo.git'
      },
      src: 'directory/to/deploy'
    },
  },
})
```

Have you tried wrapping with braces and using the single quotes for the src?

```
  git_deploy: {
    your_target: {
      options: {
        url: 'git@github.com:Diope/diope.github.io.git'
      },
      src: '/_site'
    },
  },
```

Comment: Close, I had it as `'/_site'`, and it doesn't really like. Changing it to `'_site/'` fixed my issue. Sad it took me so long to notice it. At one point I rewrote my gruntfile completely hoping muscle memory would fix what I was missing with my eyes, ha. Thanks for suggestion though, cheer!

Answer (score 0):

After waking up from a long overdue siesta, I noticed the problem immediately. I had a leading "/" for my source location.